# OOP: Aggregation/Dependency confusion

Tags: c#, oop

I know the definitions of Aggregation{by reference and by value} and Dependency but can I say it like this? I am not talking about life-time or ownership, just simple implementation.

Aggregation is the class level declaration, if I instantiate that declared object in a method than its Aggregation by reference. If I instantiate that declaration in constructor of the class than its aggregation by value or Composition.

Dependency by object variable is simply the declaration and instantiation of an object in the body of a method.

We do aggregation so we can use the same object multiple times without creating a new object for the same work.

We do dependency for shorter scopes.

[image]

The red underlined part is Aggregation by value and green underlined part is Dependency.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: I know about scope of variable, I am going to use the connection variable multiple times so I made it a class level declaration.

Comment: Just asking if my concept of aggregation and dependency is right.

Comment: Also this is not an OOP way to write a class. You need to read about Bobby Tables, there is no `Employee` class, there is no separation of concern on this class, the DbConnection is never closed, ***you are using an image to send text***, this is the wrong place to ask for a code review, your constructor can throw an exception, and takes a long time to complete.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because because this belongs in Code Review.

Comment: @Aron It seems DbHandler is very dependent on OleDbConnection. it also appears that DbHandler has control over the lifespan of OleDbConnection (and doesn't expose the instance externally), so this would be Composition, not Aggregation. But yes, OP's class isn't SOLID by any means.

Comment: My class is not complete I know that. Its just an exemplary piece of code.

My teacher told me there are two types of Aggregations. 
1. By value
2. By reference

Aggregation by value is what you're calling Composition.

Comment: Suppose there is another object "XYZ" created in some method of DBHandler, it is only limited to the life of that method, if I declare that "XYZ" object in DBHandler as a class property then it will stay alive as long as the DBHandler object itself is alive. So in other words, class level declarations are aggregation, if its instantiated in constructor then its composition other wise its aggregation by reference.

Hmm?

Comment: @Waleed This actually sounds like its a UML style question...which I know very little about. However, `by value`/`by ref` sounds like it has something to do with pointers etc. If this is the case, `C#` is not a very good language to demonstrate the difference. In `C++` a `by value` dependency would involve a copy of the object which the target would now control, whereas a `by ref` would only copy the reference, which would imply (but not always mean) that control remains on the calling scope. `C#` deals with this through the concept of `struct` and `class`.

Comment: @Aron Alright, look at this example: i3.minus.com/jbg1Zms3FPVlNk.png What is the relation of Tires object in both classes?

Comment: @Waleed Please stop sending images. I can't open that link. It is much easier to read properly formatted text than images.

Comment: `class Car{
 
 Tires t;

 public void SpinTires(){

  t = new Tires();
  t.Spin();

 }

}
class Truck{
  
 public void StopTires(){

  Tires t = new Tires();
  t.Stop();

 }

}
`

Answer (score 0):

Here the definition of dependency is more suitable than aggregation.
See the definition of dependency below...
Relationship between objects while they are associated, aggregated or composed. This kind of relationship develops while one object invokes another object’s functionality in order to accomplish some task.

So you can assert that it is dependency.